# Can't make execfile() variables be global instead of local

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
#This function loads the tokens for the specified account. If the tokens are not found, it quits the script.
def selectAccountTokens():

global OAUTH_TOKEN
global OAUTH_SECRET
global CONSUMER_KEY
global CONSUMER_SECRET

if args.account == 'acc1':
    execfile('tokens/acc1.py')
    print "Account tokens were successfully loaded."

elif args.account == 'acc2':
    execfile('tokens/acc2.py')
    print "Account tokens were successfully loaded."

elif args.account == 'acc3':
    execfile('tokens/acc3.py')
    print "Account tokens were successfully loaded."

elif args.account == 'acc4':
    execfile('tokens/acc4.py')
    print "Account tokens were successfully loaded."

else:
    print "Account tokens were not found, or the argument is invalid."
    quit()
```

When I run it without making the variables `OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET` global, it fails.

I then made them global variables, but still when I run `print OAUTH_TOKEN`, it returns nothing.

I know I shouldn't be using global variables, but I can't figure a way to do it without global variables. Even though, the function is not populating the variables.

The contents of `tokens/acc1.py` is:

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = "gaergbaerygh345heb5rstdhb"
OAUTH_SECRET = "gm8934hg9ehrsndz9upnv09w5eng9utrh"
CONSUMER_KEY = "mdfiobnf9xdunb9438gj28-3qjejgrseg"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "esgmiofdpnpirenag8934qn-ewafwefdvzsvdfbf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`global` statement does not affect the environment the [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) execute.

Explicitly passing [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) will solve your problem:

```
execfile('tokens/acc1.py', globals())
```

BTW, the `if .. elif ... elif ..` can be reduced if you use [string formatting operator `%`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) or [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
if args in ('acc1', 'acc2', 'acc3', 'acc4'):
    execfile('tokens/%s.py' % args)
    print "Account tokens were successfully loaded."
else:
    print "Account tokens were not found, or the argument is invalid."
    quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. I had tried to use %s but without success, thanks for that too.