# How to load variables from file in Python

Tags: python

Say there's a variable

```
x = "/real/path/"
```

inside a text file "setting.txt", and in a config xml file "config.xml" contains a tag

```
<root>    
    <setting>setting.txt</setting> 
    ......
</root>
```

In my Python script test.py, I would like to do this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

x = "/path/placeholder"    

def load_global_setting_from_config_xml(in_xml):
    tree = ET.parse(in_xml)
    root = tree.getroot()
    config_node = root.find("setting")
    if config_node is not None:
        config_file_path = config_node.text
        if os.path.exists(config_file_path):
           execfile(config_file_path) # looks not working

load_global_setting_from_config_xml("config.xml")
print(x) #expected output is /real/path
```

it looks execfile() does not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You will have to parse the text file and XML, then use some data structure such as a dictionary to store the results.

Comment: for certain reason, simple variable assignment is preferred than dict.

Comment: "I would like to do this:" What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank , all in all, the code is supposed to use assign x to "/real/path", which is defined inside the  setting.txt.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for original execfile(),
From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695303/cant-make-execfile-variables-be-global-instead-of-local), if modify the one line:

```
execfile(config_file_path)
```

to

```
execfile(config_file_path, globals())
```

then it will work as expected.

Comment: Why use global? I think it would be better to pass arguments and return a function result.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank ， it's a legacy issue, the setting.txt in the real case may not be as clean as I posted here.